# Resetting and reinstalling Python

Tags: python

On Ubuntu (Mate) 18.04.1 LTS

My PYTHONPATH is

```
:/home/jim/ytini/yt-conda/bin:/home/jim/ytini/yt-conda/sbin

$python -V
```

returns

```
Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

So my question is, how do I start from a blank slate. ie remove ALL Python installs and reinstall a new version or Python 2.7?

Comment: your return say's you already have python 2.7 installed? why do you want to reinstall it?

Comment: I ask because messing with your python install can be risky as many packages require it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would be knowing this and it is not a solution to your question but

Python 2.7 will not be maintained past 2020. Originally, there was no official date. Recently, that date has been updated to January 1, 2020.

**Please avoid using** 
[Python 2.7](https://pythonclock.org/)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are probably using an older version of the Anaconda. Instead of removing the Python itself, I would rather either update the conda or remove it completely(the official manual is [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html)) and get a new version from the website.
By default, the following command should remove Conda:

```
rm -rf ~/miniconda
```

If is doesn't work, try `conda` or `anaconda` instead of `miniconda`

As for updating, you can run `update conda` in the terminal. Each version allows you to use multiple Python versions in the separate environments, so I believe it is the best solution.